# 2-positivity to 3-positivity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Let $B\in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $S_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$. Suppose $I_3\otimes I_2+B\otimes X+B^*\otimes X^*\geq 0$ for all $2$-by-$2$ compressions $X$ of $S_3$. Can we conclude $I_3\otimes I_3+B\otimes S_3+B^*\otimes {S_3}^*\geq 0$?

---